# Best option to use while generating a Field inside a Form on loading

Tags: jquery, cakephp

i m having a doubt regarding which one is better option to use ?

```
  $("<input id="input1"></input>").appendTo("#Form");

       OR
 using $('<?php echo $form->input();?>').appendTo("#Form");
```

Comment: I do not believe the latter will work, it appears to be a confusion of contexts; server side php and client side javascript

Comment: @Dave: The php will run first leaving in its place something like `<input type='text' id='someCakeId'>`, which will then be evaluated by javascript in runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the framework's helpers is always a better option. So here,

```
$('<?php echo $form->input();?>').appendTo("#Form");
```

Is indeed the best solution.